# Bug in Function to detect mouse direction

Tags: javascript, html, css, mouse

i have written a function to detect mouse direction and it works but it has a bug.When i put mouse's pointer from left into the div for the first time the function calculate that mouse's pointer has moved to right direction when it is called for the first time,then it works well.I don't know if i explained wll my issue but you can easily see the bug in your browser's console seeing at the first printed values.

This is my code

```
<body>
    <div id="padre-relative">

    </div>
</body>



#padre-relative{
    position:relative;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: red;
    margin-left:300px;

}





window.onload=function(){

 var storageMousePositionX=0;

         var positionMouseX=0;


             document.getElementById("padre-relative").onmousemove= function(){


                      positionMouseX=event.clientX;

    if(positionMouseX > storageMousePositionX){

        console.log("right");

    }
    if(positionMouseX < storageMousePositionX){
        console.log("left");

    }
    storageMousePositionX=positionMouseX;

};    

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is beacause you set your var storageMousePositionX to 0 on load. You should set it for the first time when you enter the div.

```
document.getElementById("padre-relative").onmouseenter = function(){
  storageMousePositionX = event.clientX;
}
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/30ma7fo1/5/)

Comment: oh god it is strange,i had done the same thing but it doesn't work:)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are initializing `storageMousePositionX` to 0, so the first time your `onmousemove` handler fires, `event.clientX` will always be greater than 0, so it will always log "right" the first time.

One way to fix it would be to initialize it to -1 and then check against that value so you don't log something the first time the mouse moves over the div:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var storageMousePositionX=-1;

    document.getElementById("padre-relative").onmousemove = function(){
        var positionMouseX=event.clientX;

        if (storageMousePositionX > -1) {
            if(positionMouseX > storageMousePositionX){
                console.log("right");    
            }
            if(positionMouseX < storageMousePositionX){
                console.log("left");
            }
        }
        storageMousePositionX = positionMouseX;
    };

};
```